# How to send SFTP file download to background?

Tags: command-line, sftp

Is it possible to:

1. execute sftp command on remote machine and download a file (`ssh user@machine`, `sftp user2@server`, `get file`)
2. then, send download to background, so I can turn my local computer off

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong:
1)You are connected locally on machine A.  2)You want to connect through SSH on machine B.  3)On B's shell, you want to execute a remote sftp download from machine C. 4)You then want do shutdown machine A. Is that correct?

Comment: A - my local computer; B - remote server 1; C - remote server 2; I want to type `ssh user@B` on my A machine, then `sftp user@C` and `get some_file.tar.gz` on B machine; so, I would like to sftp download a file from C to B and shut down my A machine, leaving remote B and C running

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `screen` on machine B, start the download and detach afterwards:

On machine A:

`ssh user@B`

On machine B:

```
screen
sftp user@C
get some_file.tar.gz
Ctrl-a d
logout
```

Never tried but could work.

Edit: later, log back in and use `screen -x` to reconnect to the running session. Then, shut it down properly so that it isn't consuming the server's resources.

Comment: it works! thanks a lot :) extremely useful command...

Comment: and for a funkier screen on ubuntu, try out byobu.

Comment: work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the "detach" feature of screen, there's a program called "dtach" that provides only that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the character & (ampersand) behind a command runs it in background. However, I don't know how to do it after a command has already been executed, nor do I know whether this works on remote machines.

Comment: `&` would be OK, but I don't know any `--password` option I can pass through command line (so I can't do something like `sftp --password=abc user@server:file.tar.gz &`)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions to this issue.

One option is to use the `screen` command, however seems a little complex.

The best way I have found is sending the job to the background.

In your case the command would be

```
scp user@machine:~/filename.ext /tmp &
scp -r user@machine:~/dirname /tmp &
```